# Searching with a defined query in Django / Python

Tags: python, json, django, api

Currently as it stands I have a search bar and a button on my homepage like so.

```
<div class="input-group">
<input id="address" type="textbox" placeholder="City or Zipcode" class="form-control">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="addressSearch">Search</button>
</span>
</div>
```

I have created a api.py file which is within my websites folder which looks like so.

```
import urllib2
import json

locu_api = '****'

def loc_search(query):
    api_key = locu_api
    url = 'https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?api_key=' + api_key
    locality = query.replace(' ', '%20')
    final_url = url + "&locality=" + locality + "&category=restaurant"
    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(final_url)
    data = json.load(json_obj)

    for item in data['objects']:
        print item['name']
        print item['phone']
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is when the user search's for a city e.g. New York then the loc_search(query) is called populating the search field '(query)' with the users input and the data then being displayed.

I haven't much experience with either django or api's so any help would be invaluable. Thanks again

Comment: Note that you have exposed your api key, which is probably not a good idea.

Comment: The edited value can still be accessed by seeing the edits!

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much its just a simple test I wont be using the key listed in my site :)

Comment: any idea's at all? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not really experienced in django too, but  have been working around for 3 months now, i will advise you to make use of the django-auto-complete-light or django-ajax-selects for your frontend search in the navigation bar, and django-salmonela for your backend fields. those are helpful. and the input tag doesn't really work with your django forms, so you'll have to use a class in your div tag and explicitly call each form field using  the {{ form.fieldName }} then make use of the widget to reference your template tags, or just use the above packages which know much better how to handle your fields.

example:

within your template:

```
<div class="container text-center form-horizontal topSpace">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'create-recipe' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}

             {{ form.non_field_errors }}

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.name.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Name:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-1">
                                    {# <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-name" placeholder="Enter your name">#}
                                    {{ form.name }}
                                </div>
                </div><!-- end form-name-->

            {{ form.as_p }}

        <input type="submit" value="Add Recipe">
    </form>
</div>
```

then in your form:

```
class RecipeForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm, forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Recipe
    exclude = []
```